# Stuck at await When Sending Transactions

Tags: angular, ethereum, web3js, metamask

I'm writing an Angular web app that communicates with the Ethereum network. In the app, I have the following method:

```
async onSubmit() {
    const accounts = await this.web3.eth.getAccounts();
 
    this.message = 'Waiting on transaction success...';
 
    await this._lottery.methods.enter().send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: this.web3.utils.toWei(this.value, 'ether')
    });
 
    this.message = 'You have been entered!';
}
```

The method is fired on a form submission event. The state of the contract gets updated upon the call of this method, but it's kinda stuck at the `await` line and does not move to the following lines once it gets back.

Interestingly enough, I don't face this problem when reading from the network, i.e., `call` instead of `send`.

P.S. I'm using web3 v1.0.0 with Rinkeby network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the the issue comes from the Metamask chrome extension. Rolling back the Metamask extension to v4.11 seems to solve this problem.